# Lost record due to the collapse of versioning

Tags: sql, postgresql

there are two tables. You must connect them while maintaining versioning 
Table "ft":

```
| id | param1 | param2 |          dfrom        |           dto         |
|----|--------|--------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
|  1 |  'SS'  |  'DD'  | '01.04.2010 12:30:20' | '17.04.2010 13:10:14' |
|  1 |  'ZZ'  |  null  | '17.04.2010 13:10:15' | '18.01.2010 04:13:15' |
|  1 |  'ZZ'  |  'GG'  | '18.01.2010 04:13:16' | '12.12.2010 00:00:00' |
```

Table "st":

```
| id | param3 |          dfrom        |           dto         |
|----|--------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
|  1 |  'KK'  | '01.03.2010 12:30:20' | '02.04.2010 13:10:14' |
|  1 |  'QQ'  | '02.04.2010 13:10:15' | '12.12.2010 00:00:00' |
```

Result:

```
| id | param1 | param2 | param3 |          dfrom        |            dto        |
|  1 |  'ZZ'  |  'DD'  |  'QQ'  | '18.01.2010 04:13:16' | '12.12.2010 00:00:00' |
|  1 |  null  |  null  |  'KK'  | '01.03.2010 12:30:20' | '01.04.2010 12:30:19' |
|  1 |  'SS'  |  'DD'  |  'KK'  | '01.04.2010 12:30:20' | '02.04.2010 13:10:14' |
|  1 |  'SS'  |  'DD'  |  'QQ'  | '02.04.2010 13:10:15' | '17.04.2010 13:10:14' |
|  1 |  'ZZ'  |  null  |  'QQ'  | '17.04.2010 13:10:15' | '18.01.2010 04:13:15' |
```

I lost 2 line, I can not understand how to take into account the fact that one record appeared before all (dfrom) but closed in the range of the other two records

Comment: My request:

select 
 a.id, param1, param2, param3,
 case when b.dfrom < a.dfrom then b.dfrom else a.dfrom end as dfrom,
 case when b.dto < a.dto then b.dto else a.dto end as dto
from
 ft a cross join st b
where
 a.id = b.id and (a.dfrom between b.dfrom and b.dto or a.dto between b.dfrom and b.dto) not result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge 2 tables while maintaining versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534200/how-do-i-merge-2-tables-while-maintaining-versioning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to do split the data by date (and presumably `id`) and recombine:

```
with cte as (
      select id, param1, param2, null as param3, dfrom, 'ft' as which
      from ft
      union all
      select id, null, null, param3, dfrom, 'st'
      from st
     )
select id, dfrom, lead(dfrom) over (order by dfrom),
       max(max(param1)) over (partition by grp_ft) as param1,
       max(max(param2)) over (partition by grp_ft) as param2,
       max(max(param3)) over (partition by grp_st) as param3
from (select cte.*,
             max(dfrom) filter (where which = 'ft') over (partition by id order by dfrom) as grp_ft,
             max(dfrom) filter (where which = 'st') over (partition by id order by dfrom) as grp_st
      from cte
     ) cte
group by id, dfrom, grp_ft, grp_st;
```

This splits the data by the param values.  It then uses window functions to recombine them, accumulating the previous value, if any.  If Postgres supported the `IGNORE NULLS` option on `LAG()`, the subquery would not be necessary.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e000663f27272d7c14bac17a6e68ce59) is a db<>fiddle.

This version does not take the final date into account.  The issue is that you don't explain what to do (if you want a revision, I would recommend asking a new question).

The issue is that you appear to have valid `NULL` values in the data.  Normally, I would just reset the values to `NULL`, but that seems like an assumption too far.

Comment: Thank you! Bu my work:

select 
 a.id, param1, param2, param3,
 case 
  when b.dfrom < a.dfrom then b.dfrom 
  else a.dfrom 
 end,
 case 
  when b.dto < a.dto then b.dto 
  else a.dto 
 end as dto
from 
 ft a 
 left join st b 
on 
 a.id is not distinct from b.id
union all
select 
 party_rk, null as param1, null as param2, param3, 
 dfrom, dto
from 
 st

keep working!))